# how can I convert 'for loop' to numpy array calculation?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to execute following 'for loop'.
However, after waiting for several hours, what I've got was the error message that says out of memory.
Thus, I want to convert the for loop to numpy in order to reduce time and memory require for this calculation.
Unfortunately, I failed to do it.
It would be a great help if anyone can suggest the way to convert the following code into the one that uses the numpy array.

The type of la,lo is 'pandas.core.series.Series',
and the type of ste is 'obspy.core.stream.Stream'.

```
def distance(a,i):
    return math.sqrt(((ste[a].stats.sac.stla-la[i])**2)+((ste[a].stats.sac.stlo-lo[i])**2))

def traveltime(a):
    return model.get_travel_times(source_depth_in_km=35, distance_in_degree=a, phase_list=["S"], receiver_depth_in_km=0)[0].time
```

```
di=[(la[i],lo[i],distance(a,i), distance(b,i)) for i in range(len(lo))
    for a in range(len(ste))
    for b in range(len(ste)) if a<b]
didf=pd.DataFrame(di)

latot=didf[0]
lotot=didf[1]
dia=didf[2]
dib=didf[3]
```

```
tt=[]
for i in range(len(di)):
    try:
        tt.append((latot[i],lotot[i],traveltime(dia[i])-traveltime(dib[i])))
    except IndexError:
        continue

ttdf=pd.DataFrame(tt)

final=[(win[j],ttdf[0][i],ttdf[1][i],(ttdf[2][i]-shift[j])**2) for i in range(len(ttdf))
      for j in range(len(ccdf))]
```

P.S)
For more information, I add the codes that are executed after the codes above. These worked well when I put smaller amount of data. Also, I add a image I get after executing all these codes.

```
fidf=pd.DataFrame(final)
titles = {0: 'winnum', 1: 'latitude', 2: 'longitude', 3: 'difference'}
fidf.rename(columns=titles, inplace=True)
```

```
gls={}

for i in range(10):
    fidf=fidf.sample(frac=0.9,replace=True,random_state=1)
    grouped=fidf['difference'].groupby([fidf['winnum'],fidf['latitude'],fidf['longitude']]).sum()
    grouped=grouped.loc[grouped.groupby('winnum').idxmin()]
    gls[i]=grouped.reset_index()
```

```
median=pd.Panel(gls).median(axis=0)
std=pd.Panel(gls).std(axis=0)

print(median)
print(std)
```

[image]

Comment: What are you wanting to create into a numpy array? Also, the code looks incomplete.

Comment: I've heard it saves time and memory by calculating numpy array rather than operating for loop. There are additional codes before and after these lines. However, since it is long, I didn't display all of them here. And it worked well when I put smaller amount of data.

Comment: The code looks incomplete, can you add and format it correctly? What commands are executed after inside the inner loop in the last line?

Comment: I added codes in my post, and also the result I get after executing all the codes.